# timeout for SCM to kill a service that won't stop

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I'm trying to figure out what happens if the SCM sends a stop request to a service but the service does not stop within a specific interval. I've seen passing references in blogs and forums to a 30 second timeout (not backed up by any MSDN references) and also to registry keys called [HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control]ServicesPipeTimeout and [HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control]WaitToKillServiceTimeout

On my Windows 7 dev laptop, neither of these registry keys exists. What happens when I try to stop a service from the control panel is that after 2 minutes, the control panel says the service is not responding but it leaves it running and never kills the process.

Is there any documentation to describe the expected behaviour? specifically in my service, am I expected to put in my own timer to kill any errant threads if they don't finish within a reasonable time?

I'm using the .Net ServiceBase class for my implementation